# I am currently working on my face recognition open-cv and this issue keeps showing after I log it

Tags: python, face-recognition

Exception in Tkinter callback

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\Claire\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2898, in get_loc
> return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
> File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
> File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 101, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
> File "pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1675, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
> File "pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1683, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
> KeyError: 'Id'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 1702, in **call**
> return self.func(*args)
> File "C:\Users\Claire\Desktop\New folder (6)\login-verification-master\run.py", line 161, in login_submit
> TrackImages(a)
> File "C:\Users\Claire\Desktop\New folder (6)\login-verification-master\run.py", line 135, in TrackImages
> aa=df.loc[df['Id'] == Id]['Name'].values
> File "C:\Users\Claire\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2906, in **getitem**
> indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
> File "C:\Users\Claire\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2900, in get_loc
> raise KeyError(key) from err
> KeyError: 'Id'

This is the code that produces the error.

```
def TrackImages(UserId):
    recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()#cv2.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()
    recognizer.read("TrainingImageLabel\Trainner.yml")
    harcascadePath = "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
    faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(harcascadePath);
    df=pd.read_csv("Details\Details.csv")
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX          
    run_count=0;run=True
    while run:
        
        ret, im =cam.read()
        gray=cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        faces=faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.2,5)    
        for(x,y,w,h) in faces:
            cv2.rectangle(im,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(225,0,0),2)
            Id, conf = recognizer.predict(gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])
            print(Id, conf)
            if(conf < 50):
                aa=df.loc[df.get['Id'] == Id]['Name'].values
                tt=str(Id)+"-"+aa
                if (str(Id)==UserId):
                    print(Id, conf)
                    message.configure(text="Face Recognised Successfully")
                    run=False
            else:
                Id='Unknown'                
                tt=str(Id)            
            cv2.putText(im,str(tt),(x,y+h), font, 1,(255,255,255),2)        
        run_count += 1    
        cv2.imshow('im',im) 
        if (cv2.waitKey(1)==ord('q') or run_count==150):
            message.configure(text="Unable to Recognise Face")
            break
    
    cam.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    


def login_submit():
    a=txt.get()
    b=txt2.get()
    if (a in data):
        if(data[a] == b):
            TrackImages(a)
        else:
            message.configure(text="Id and Password does not Match")
    else:
        message.configure(text="Entered Id does not Exists")

    login_clear()
```

Comment: `print(Id, conf)` Did it print the Id?

Comment: Yes it is printed

Comment: 3456789 18.83621867366029 here is the example

Answer (score 0):

Your error is here:

```py
aa=df.loc[df.get['Id'] == Id]['Name'].values
```

You have used `square` brackets instead of `small` brackets

Use this instead:

```py
aa=df.loc[df.get('Id') == Id]['Name'].values
```

OR, you can also use this:

```py
aa=df.loc[df['Id'] == Id]['Name'].values
```

Comment: and if I use this the I got the same error key error : ID

Comment: Check in your dataframe whether it is ID or Id. Also show us what your dataframe looks like

Comment: row = [Id , name] here is my data frame.

Comment: Update the question be adding your dataframe

Comment: when after i finish log in the account that I registered the camera is displayed and I get this line Id='Unknown'

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code where my dataframe stored.

```
def TakeImages():        
        Id=(txt3.get())
        name=(txt4.get())
        ret=0
        if (Id not in data):
            cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
            harcascadePath = "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
            detector=cv2.CascadeClassifier(harcascadePath)
            sampleNum=0
            while(True):
                ret, img = cam.read()
                gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                faces = detector.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
                for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
                    cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)        
                    #incrementing sample number 
                    sampleNum=sampleNum+1
                    #saving the captured face in the dataset folder TrainingImage
                    cv2.imwrite("TrainingImage\ "+name +'.'+Id+'.'+ str(sampleNum) + ".jpg", gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])
                    #display the frame
                    cv2.imshow('frame',img)
                #wait for 100 miliseconds 
                if cv2.waitKey(100) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                    break
                # break if the sample number is morethan 100
                elif sampleNum>100:
                    break
            cam.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows() 
            res = "Images Saved for ID : " + Id +" Name : "+ name
            row = [Id , name]
            with open('Details\Details.csv','a+') as csvFile:
                writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
                writer.writerow(row)
            csvFile.close()
            message.configure(text= res)
            ret=1
        else:
            res = "User name Already Exists...Try another one!!!"
            message.configure(text= res)
        return ret
```

here is what my csv looks like.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLqqo.png)

Comment: can you show what your csv data looks like? Is your error solved?

Comment: If `Id` is showing unknown then change the condition of `if` statement. Use this `if(conf > 30):`

Comment: Not yet. I used so many options and still end up with the same error. My csv data is located in the Details folder(as what can you see in the code above) of root folder of run.py the data stored in the microsoft excel.

Comment: Same error is showing. It display some data but still the ID is not recognise

Comment: Update the question by showing what your csv looks like. Show first few rows

Comment: I added my csv file please see the attach image that I post.

Comment: There is no any `Id` and `Name` as header in your csv dataset. Your error lies in your dataset. Add `Id` and `Name` as header in dataset.

Comment: It works!! Thanks for guiding me. I hope you have a great day

Comment: Help me also by ticking my answer :)

Comment: I receive a new error numpy.core._exceptions._UFuncNoLoopError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U21'), dtype('<U21')) -> dtype('<U21')
every time I log in my account the error appears.

Comment: You can ask this by opening a new question in stackoverflow. Also you have not ticked my answer so I might not feel motivated to answer your question as it takes a lot of time for me to look into anyone's question.